# How to split a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Say I have a list of strings like so:

```
list = ["Jan 1", "John Smith", "Jan 2", "Bobby Johnson"]
```

How can I split them into two separate lists like this? My teacher mentioned something about indexing but didn't do a very good job of explaining it

```
li1 = ["Jan 1", "John Smith"]
li2 = ["Jan 2", "Bobby Johnson"]
```

Comment: You can check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/5488275) and answers (like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/5488275)) to learn more about slicing in Python.

Answer (score 5):

Well, use list slicing:

```
li1 = my_list[:2]
li2 = my_list[2:]
```

BTW, don't use the name `list` for a variable because you are shadowing the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 1):

If your list is longer than just two entries you could do this:

```
zip(list[0::2],list[1::2])
```

Output:

```
[('Jan 1', 'John Smith'), ('Jan 2', 'Bobby Johnson')]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of ways to do make it work with lists of arbitrary length in a clean and simple manner:

```
all_lists = (list[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(list), 2))
```

And then you can access new lists by:

```
li1 = all_lists[0]
li2 = all_lists[1]
```

Or just iterate through them:

```
for new_list in all_lists:
    print(new_list)
```

As `all_lists` is a generator (in both Python 2.X and 3.X) it will also work on large chunks of data.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the list isn't always going to be the same, or known from the start you can do this:

```
original_list = [YOUR ORIGINAL LIST]

A = [:len(original_list)/2]
B = [len(original_list)/2:]
```

A will be the first half and B will be the second half.